# filtering spgridview

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

while filtering spgridview i have applied filterexpression "{1} = '{0}'"; because my values are of type double or integer. but while filtering for values like 0.5 or like 0.xxxx.... it does not filter properly if anybody encountered it before, plz provide solution to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly go through the article link provided below that can be help for you as it talks about glitches in filters
http://www.reversealchemy.net/blog/2009/05/24/building-a-spgridview-control-part-2-filtering/

Comment: +1 This is a very good resource when working with SPGridView filters

Comment: it was an obvious link that one could have tried as it was among top 5 on google. it actually has lot of limitations , while comparing with default behaviour in sharepoint lists so if you otherwise knows some other source which is guauranteed to be good enough. please help.